# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple error while image processing

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv

Sonuc= Kesilmis_Kare.copy()
cnts, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(Renk_Fılte_Sonucu,cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

```
Max_Genislik=0
Max_Uzunluk=0
Max_Index=-1

for t in range(len(cnts)):
    cnt=cnts[t]
    x,y,w,h= cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    if(w>Max_Genislik and h>Max_Uzunluk):
        Max_Uzunluk= h
        Max_Genislik= w
        Max_Index= t,

if(len(cnts)>0):
    x,y,w,h= cv2.boundingRect(cnts[Max_Index])
    cv2.rectangle(Sonuc,(x,y),(x+w,y+h), (0,255,0),2)
```

I took
x,y,w,h= cv2.boundingRect(cnts[Max_Index])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

this error can you help me pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Max_Index= t,
```

This line turns `Max_Index` into a tuple.

```
x,y,w,h= cv2.boundingRect(cnts[Max_Index])
```

In this line you use `Max_Index` as a list index, but as error message says, it can be only integer, so you should use another variable.